# How to load the JSON data into the Jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I use the following way to load the data into the jqgrid.I cant able to load the **json data** into the jqgrid.So i parse the json to array like **mydata=json.parse(jsondata)**.Then i bind this ***array(mydata)*** into jqgrid using **datatype: "local"**.my question is **How to bind the json data into the jqgrid?**

```
         $("#datagrid").jqGrid({

                    datatype: "local", 
                    data: mydata,
                    colNames:['companyid','company', 'price', 'Change','perchange','LastUpdated'],
                    colModel:[
                        {name:'companyid',index:'companyid', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
                        {name:'company',index:'company', width:100,editable:true},
                        {name:'price',index:'price', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
                        {name:'Change',index:'Change', width:100,editable:true,editoptions:{size:25}},
                        {name:'perchange',index:'perchange', width:100, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}},
                        {name:'LastUpdated',index:'LastUpdated', width:200, align:"right",editable:true,editoptions:{size:10}}
                    ],
                    rowNum:10,
                    rowList:[3,6],
                    loadonce: true,
                    pager: '#navGrid',
                    sortname: 'companyid',
                    sortorder: "asc", 
                    height: 210,
                    width:600,
                    onSelectRow: function(id)
                                 {
                                    getID = jQuery("#datagrid").jqGrid('getCell', id, 'companyid')
                                 },
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption:"JQ GRID"
                });
```

JSON format:

```
    [
        {
            "company": "test",
            "price": 98,
            "Change": 8,
            "perchange": 8,
            "LastUpdated": "2",
            "companyid": 2
        },
        {
            "company": "test123",
            "price": 1,
            "Change": 1,
            "perchange": 1,
            "LastUpdated": "1",
            "companyid": 3
        },
        {
            "company": "abc",
            "price": 1234,
            "Change": 123,
            "perchange": 1,
            "LastUpdated": "1",
            "companyid": 1
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you need to define `id` of the row in the input data. The `id` attribute of every row (`<tr>`) will be set in the corresponding value. Because you have already `companyid` which could play the role it would be enough to add `key: true` to the properties of `"companyid"` column in `colModel`.

The problem with loading of the date from the server directly (inclusive loading from the file) you can solve by adding `jsonReader` which describe the format of input data. Because you use `loadonce: true` the `total`, `records` and the `page` properties of input data will be ignored and you can use `jsonReader` in the following simple form:

```js
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; }}
```

The corresponding demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user-2.htm).

If you need to load the data from the array of data which you posted your code should directly work ( see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user-1.htm)). I suppose use have some other problem in the parsing of JSON data, but you don't posted the corresponding code.

The advice about the `id` and `key: true` are still take place. You can use `localReader: {id: "companyid"}` for the second case and the same property `id: "companyid"` in the `jsonReader` alternatively. I personally prefer to use `key: true` because the code is easy to read and it's independent from the reader used.